# How can I call a function (Expression<Func<T, Boolean>> predicate) with a predicate that does nothing?

Tags: c#

I have this method:

```
public async Task<List<T>> GetDocumentItemsAsync<T>(Expression<Func<T, Boolean>> predicate) where T : class
```

I am calling the method like this:

```
var Views = await cosmosManager.GetDocumentItemsAsync<LogViews>(x => x.Activity == "Crash");
```

Now there is a case where I don't want to have any check at all and don't want to check the values of Activity.

Is there a way I can call that method as when I try leaving the parameters blank I get an error message.

Comment: What is the difference in your mind between "I don't want to have any check at all", and "I have a check that always returns true"? If there is a difference can you say what it is, to clarify the question? If there is not a difference, well, then you know the answer to your question.

Comment: `cosmosManager.GetDocumentItemsAsync<LogViews>(_ => true)`

Comment: Is there any reason you've using `Expression<Func<T, Boolean>>` and not just `Func<T, Boolean>` ?

Comment: @Sean: Likely the asynchronous method passes the query to a database.

Comment: Are you trying to create a "do-nothing" condition in a LINQ query, to implement a catch-all query? Just *remove* the `Where` clause if you don't want it. Or use a different method to return a query that returns everything. The expression doesn't do nothing, it will end up in the query sent to the server. Database servers don't parse queries from scratch each time, they reuse execution plans. Catch-all queries can easily result in inefficient execution plans and slow queries

Comment: @Sean Might be because OP is passing `IQueryable` instead of `IEnumerable`. Similar to what Eric said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Null Object Pattern. Provide and overload looking like this:

```
public async Task<List<T>> GetDocumentItemsAsync<T>() where T : class
{
    return await GetDocumentItemsAsync<T>(t => true);
}
```

Unfortunately, you can't just default the parameter in the original to t => true, since a lambda is not a compile time constant.

I presume you want the default to be `true`, but equally you could make it `false`.